# Need to make the visible currency is different from the real currency

Tags: currency

My bank is accepting only Turkish lira`(currency) and the visible currency of store is on Dollars. However, when a customer makes the payment I want the currency (as hidden process) switch to Turkish lira` .

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link in order to figure out how to give your customers the option of choosing the currency they want.
I think this should be helpful:
[http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/][1]